# sound doesn't stop when the user press back key

Tags: android, audio, playback

I'm newbie in android programming. I have the following code with a mediaplayer. when the user presses the back key or goes to another activity the sound won't stop.

what's the problem? I have the onDestory method but my problem exists!

```
    public class Elementary1Activity extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        private SeekBar seekBar;
        private ImageButton startMedia;
        private ImageButton pauseMedia;
        private MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.elementary1);             


            AudioControl();    

        }

        public void AudioControl(){
            seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarnew2);
            startMedia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbuttonnew2);
            pauseMedia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pausebuttonnew2);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
            startMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
            pauseMedia.setOnClickListener(this); 
        }    

        public void run() {
            int currentPosition= 0;
            int total = mp.getDuration();
            while (mp!=null && currentPosition<total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }            
                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
            }
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            pauseMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startMedia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (v.equals(startMedia)) {
                if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) return;
                if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                    mp.start();
                    return;
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Elementary1Activity.this, R.raw.e1);
                mp.start();            

                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                new Thread(this).start();
            }

            if (v.equals(pauseMedia) && mp!=null) {
                mp.pause();
                pauseMedia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                startMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }       

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
           super.onStop();
           mp= MediaPlayer.create(Elementary1Activity.this,R.raw.e1);
           if(mp.isPlaying())
           {
             mp.stop();
             mp.release();
             finish();
           }
          }


        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser) mp.seekTo(progress);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new mediaplayer in onDestroy()?

Comment: what should i do? please help me. i'm newbie and i am in trouble with this issue.

Comment: Destroy() is called when the process itself is destroyed-- by switching processes, you're merely pausing the activity. Also, it makes no sense to create a new MediaPlayer object in the destroy() function because it's about to get deleted anyway. `mp` is either already created or not by that point, so check to see if it exists, and if it is, pause it, like in Andreaoid's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use onPause() event in your Elementary1Activity to manage the music pausing.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp!=null) {
        mp.pause();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things. If you want that MediaPlayer stop when you push back button and you want to close the app the best option is:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    if(mp != null){    
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop
        }
        mp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And if you want to make that MediaPlayer stop when you change of activity:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    }
}
```

Apart of that, don't create a new MediaPlayer when you want to close your app.